# "Nothing to be done for makefile"

Tags: makefile

first, thanks to all.

I ' ve been kind of 3 hours trying to find out whats wrong, I have done a deep research on the internet and I found nothing that worked for me.
I' ve tried a lot of examples which ended the same way; missing separator or nothing to be done.

What could it be?

My .c and .h are called the same way 3enRayaPunteros.c/h

Here's my makefile's code:

```
Juego: 3enRayaPunteros.o
gcc -o Juego 3enRayaPunteros.o
3enRayaPunteros.o: 3enRayaPunteros.c 3enRayaPunteros.h
    gcc -c 3enRayaPunteros.c
```

Thank you so much:

Comment: A common trap with Makefiles is that they expect a tab character, not spaces, which does not display on websites.

Comment: Please show an actual makefile, the actual command you invoked, and the actual error you got (via cut/paste).  Paraphrasing and generic statements like "it doesn't work" can't be helped.  _missing separator_ is usually because you're using spaces when you should be using TAB characters (note it must be an actual TAB, so be sure your text editor is not "helpfully" converting your TAB into spaces).  _Nothing to be done_ may mean that nothing actually needs to be done, or your makefile could be wrong, or you could be invoking make incorrectly; we can't tell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
Juego: 3enRayaPunteros.o
    gcc -o $@ $+

3enRayaPunteros.o: 3enRayaPunteros.c 3enRayaPunteros.h
    gcc -c -o $@ $^
```

You want your executable `Juego` to depend on a `.o` file. That object file needs to depends on your source files `.c, .h, ...`.

It's common practice to refer to the target name with `$@`, refer to all the prerequisites with `$+` and refer to the first prerequisite with `$^`.

Missing seperator usually means you are mixing up `spaces` and `tabs`. Make is very fiddly when it comes to this so do **NOT** use `tabs` to indent anything but recipes. Nothing to be done means exactly what the message says: there is nothing to be done for what you asked make to do.

Comment: It is not true that you have to write `make Juego`.  There's nothing magical to make about the target named `all`; it's just a common convention in many makefiles.  make itself will always build the first explicit target it finds in the makefile, by default, no matter what its name is.

Comment: Thank you so much!